# Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] and Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to setup a simple SP app with angularjs, bootstrand and ui bootstrap, the code is copy paste from the Alert Directive example on the UI bootstrap (intention was to test if at least a simple thing work) but its not.

MY SP Page code:

```
<%-- The following 4 lines are ASP.NET directives needed when using SharePoint components --%>

<%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<%-- The markup and script in the following Content element will be placed in the <head> of the page --%>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
    <meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full" />

    <!-- Add your CSS styles to the following file -->
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Content/App.css" />

    <!-- Add your JavaScript to the following file -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/App.js"></script>
</asp:Content>

<%-- The markup in the following Content element will be placed in the TitleArea of the page --%>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
   AngularJS - Sharepoint List CRUD Sample
</asp:Content>

<%-- The markup and script in the following Content element will be placed in the <body> of the page --%>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">

    <div class="container" ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
        <div ng-controller="AlertDemoCtrl">
          <alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
          <button class='btn btn-default' ng-click="addAlert()">Add Alert</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

My app.js

```
'use strict';
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('AlertDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.alerts = [
      { type: 'danger', msg: 'Oh snap! Change a few things up and try submitting again.' },
      { type: 'success', msg: 'Well done! You successfully read this important alert message.' }
    ];

    $scope.addAlert = function () {
        $scope.alerts.push({ msg: 'Another alert!' });
    };

    $scope.closeAlert = function (index) {
        $scope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
    };
});
```

I get the 2 errors in the title

I suppose something messed up in the order of the js files?

Comment: In your appjs file, first line, define the module angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', []);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the module definition to

```
        angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', [ui.bootstrap]).....
```

you need to add ui.bootstrap as a dependency

Comment: actually the error is gone if I use [] instead of [ui.bootstrap] however I dont see the nicely designed alerts. (but the btn ng-click functionaly works fine)